# Semi-recent sci-fi movie where everyone is chipped and controlled by an evil corporation or government

Tags: story-identification, movie, technology

I’m looking for a movie I watched within the last year (likely released within the last decade), where everyone is chipped, and is in-turn controlled by an evil corporation or government. People discover this truth and are subsequently targeted and killed. The film ends with someone sending out a virus that stops the corporation/government from killing all those chipped.

This has been driving me crazy for days, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: If I remember correctly, the reasoning for the chip implants were that they helped distribute a cure for a virus.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you watch this movie? Also, was the "entity" human, alien, some type of artificial intelligence, or something else?

Comment: Apologies, by entity, I meant it was either an corporation or government. I watched the film within the last year, and I am fairly certain it was released within the last 10.

Answer (score 8):

Thanks everyone!

I’ve realized (through asking every possible person I’ve seen in person the last few days) that I was referring to the not-so-good [Dead Rising: Endgame](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_Rising:_Endgame) (2016).

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like it could be [Disturbing Behavior (1998)](https://m.imdb.com/title/tt0134619/)

Teens are chipped. The new kid and his friends try to stop it and get targeted.

Comment: I don't recall that having anything to do with government/corporations though... I thought it was just the school doing it?

Comment: No go, but thanks for the suggestion! It definitely was a much more recent movie.

Comment: @JonClements But it wasn't some rogue private school. The school board, the parents, the police ... the town's government ... were all in on it.

Answer (score 3):

Could be [Hardwired](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardwired_(film))

> In the not-too-distant future where corporations control nearly every
> aspect of human life, a man named Luke Gibson is involved in a car
> accident that claims the life of his wife and their unborn child. Luke
> has severe brain damage, but Hope Corporation agrees to implant a chip
> into his brain to save his life. He discovers that this chip also
> constantly sends advertisements until either the person obtains the
> product, or they go insane. W**hile trying to figure out why they did
> this to him and who he is, he finds out that the chip is a test
> product with a fail-safe that could kill him**. He succumbs to the
> effects but the Corporation fears that their test might be discovered,
> and they decide to activate the fail-safe. **Just before it goes off, a
> group of underground hackers led by Hal and "Keyboard" hack into the
> chip and save his life**. After using the chip to guide him away from
> Hope Corp. pursuers, they agree to try to help him remember who he is
> in exchange for assisting in their fight against Hope Corp. They show
> him that his accident was no accident but actually planned by Hope
> Corp. so they could use him as a test subject. He agrees to help but
> is captured during the attempt and taken to a facility controlled by
> Hope Corp. Luke, with the help of Punk Red and Punk Blue, manages to
> fight his way to the leader of the project, Virgil Kirkhill. Virgil is
> killed after a short confrontation, and Luke escapes. He meets up with
> "Red" and "Blue" (the only remaining members of the underground
> group). Together they vow to continue the fight until Hope Corporation
> is destroyed.

Comment: No go, but thanks for the suggestion! It was more of a “mass chip implantation” scenario, not like this or Upgrade (2018).